# low image quality in safari, jssor slider is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, jssor

I have used jssor slider on my website which works fine in all browsers except safari, in safari images are little blur.
My image size is bigger than slider Div, image size is (1207 x 708) but div is of 900 x 600 px.
please help me how can i fix this issue

Comment: Please post some code and a demo/jsfiddle.

Comment: What kind of device are you using? Could it be a retina device?

Comment: i am using simple laptop for development and testing

Comment: issue only comes when image size is bigger than slider div, otherwise it seems perfect, my problem is that i can not re-size image to decrease its quality as its working fine in all other browsers

Comment: Which laptop is it? Not a macbook pro is it? Usually pixelation does not happen when the image is resized smaller than its original size

Comment: i am using a HP probook but i have tested it on mac machine also, in safari it has same issue

Comment: Please set div size to 1200 x 800 px.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your list of slider options:

```
$HWA: false
```

HWA is HardWare Acceleration, according to the JSSOR reference - [link](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

I discovered this option via another S.O. post from JSSOR in response to someone who wanted to prevent "-webkit-transform: perspective(2000);" being injected into their code, which it does. It may, therefore, affect 3D transitions (untested).

It appears that setting `$HWA: false` also disables image resampling, thus allowing your Retina-compatible images to show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please set slider container size close to image size. If you set the container size to 1200 to 800, it should look better.

As your slider is responsible, it scales to larger size sometimes.

For some reason, there is a bit problem on safari in following case.

Assuming that you have image at size (1800 x 1200), and your slider size is (900 x 600), and your slider is responsive, it will resize to (1800 x 1200) to fit your screen.

That's to say, your image resizes from (1800 x 1200) to (900 x 600), and then to (1800 x 1200) again.
You will see image blur on safari.

The reason is that the quality lose when a larger image fit a smaller container. And when you scale it to larger size, the quality should look a bit worse.