# Jssor silder images lose quality in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

New version of Jssor will not have this problem.

---

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ianwong/rxappjrz/1/)

```js
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          var options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,

              $PauseOnHover: true, //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing, default value is false

              $ArrowKeyNavigation: true, //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
              $SlideWidth: 141, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
              $SlideHeight: 200, //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
              $SlideSpacing: 25, //Space between each slide in pixels
              $DisplayPieces: 3, //Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
              $ParkingPosition: 0, //The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled).

              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: { //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                  $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                  $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                  $AutoCenter: 2, //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                  $Steps: 1 //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
              }
          };

          var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

          //responsive code begin
          //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
          function ScaleSlider() {
              var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
              if (parentWidth) jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 800));
              else window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
          }

          ScaleSlider();

          if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
              $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
          }
          //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
          //    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
          //}
          //responsive code end

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jssor.com/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jssor.com/js/jssor.js"></script>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left:0 px; width: 420px;
        height: 245px;">
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 420px; height: 245px;
            overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/02.jpg" class="tissue_image" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/03.jpg" class="tissue_image" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/04.jpg" class="tissue_image" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/05.jpg" class="tissue_image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Demo, the images lose quality in safari, but it's OK in other browsers.

How to fix this by program?

There are some relate questions, that told to change original images size manually to fit into container, but due to some kind of reasons, i cannot change size manually, it has to be by program.

I think it needs to modify "jssor.slider.js" or "jssor.slider.js" about how to generate the slider images, but I don't know whether it's the right way to do it.

Anyone who know "jssor slider" would help me? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue with Safari and JSSOR as well. Safari is VERY picky about the specified image dimensions vs the actual image size where the rest of the major browsers seem to ignore it in favor of the responsive code. The images used in the standard demo (and in your code sample unless you changed them) are 600x300px, but you are specifying 420x245 for both the slider container AND the slides themselves. Change those two values to the actual size of the images you're using and Safari will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Retina display?

Safari resizes images to the displayed slide size, but does it badly so they appear blurred. Even more so on Retina displays because they're at 72dpi instead of 144.

The solution is to disable HardWare Acceleration in JSSOR, as detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914361/)

Try adding this to your JSSOR options:

```
$HWA: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you make the original slider at size of 'width: 420px; height: 245px;'. Please make the original size bigger.

You know, when you make a smaller slider and scale it to larger size, it may look blurry. But if you make large slider and scale it to smaller size, it won't lose quality (in Safari).